# Github BOT for google chat

Tags: github, google-hangouts

I am trying to use the Github BOT to integrate with google chat for sensung notifications on PRs, push etc.
While this may work, it asks me authorization for hangoutschatbot-dev-on-github. Just want to be sure that this is authentic and I can grant access safely.

A quick search on google for it gave this result - https://github.com/hangoutschatbot-dev-on-github

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to answer this but you should do it via google chat -> add people & bots option

search for github
Choose the bot
Follow the steps to add one or more repo there

Avoid any unverified open source code if possible.